# Which is the most powerful language, set theory or category theory?

Tags: logic, soft-question, category-theory, set-theory

As far as I know, mathematics is written based on a language which can be for example set theory or category theory. My concern is about the power of these languages. How can we realize which language is more powerful and we can construct more structures with them? Maybe, there is an assumption which implies all languages are equal, and actually, there is no strength preference although there is maybe the simplicity preference.   If it is the case, could you please clarify why you think this assumption is good and obvious?

p.s. : I am not an expert, so if you think my question is absolutely wrong or does not make sense at all, please let me know.

Comment: You can formalize category theory in material set theory (+ classes or universes) and you can formalize material set theory in category theory (because you can formalize structural set theory and then I believe, do what is described here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pure+set). But nobody can tell you, what's "better". That's very opinion-dependent, I'm afraid.

Comment: This question reads to me as "Who's more powerful, my dad or your dad?"

Comment: Regardless of which is more powerful, they are both useful, and any mathematician should get exposure to both. The thing to note is that which one works better is dependent on the material being looked at. For example, combinatorics problems(in my opinion) are more natural in terms of set theory rather than category theory. Algebraic topology on the otherhand tends to be ugly if you are relying on only set theory.   Another way to say this: you could theoretically use a screwdriver to hammer nails and you could use the back of a hammer to screw something in, but that doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @AsafKaragila As a physics student, non of them is my father :) 
This question and actually its answer is important for me, because again as a physics student who are doing some stuffs in category theory and physics,  I must convince myself this language changing is only the simplicity preference and not more.

Comment: I think the question is very valid.  We are used to so many strict hierarchies in mathematics (integers are a subset of real numbers which are a subset of complex numbers, etc), that the question makes sense.

Comment: There are answers to a similar question here:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8731/categorical-foundations-without-set-theory

Comment: @user2316040 Thanks for this really interesting link.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Set theory and category theory are both foundational theories of mathematics (they explain *basics*), but they attack *different* aspects of foundations. Set theory is largely concerned with "how do we build mathematical objects (or what could we build)" while category theory is largely concerned with "what structure to mathematical objects have (or could have)"?

Mathematicians work in *informal* set theory and *informal* category theory, which are immensly useful as lingua franca and as collections of universally useful concepts and techniques, but their formal versions are not actually needed by mathematicians for the most part. This is witnessed by the fact that the average mathematician is unable to list the axioms of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, and even of first-order logic. Yet, they are perfectly able to do complicated math.

The formal versions of set theory and category theory are of interest to people who study foundations of mathematics. These relationship between these two and computation has been known for a while. I highly recommend Bob Harper's [blog post about the Holy Trinity](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/the-holy-trinity/) for a quick read, and Steve Awodey's [From Sets to Types to Categories to Sets](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/preprints/stcsFinal.pdf) if you would like know more about the connections and their significance.

The upshot is that we can mostly translate between set theory, type theory, and category theory, and that ordinary mathematicians could do their mathematics in either of the three systems, but the systems are not exclusive. In fact, a smart mathematician will be aware of their connections and will take advantage of them.

Comment: As an analog, I guess, you might say that anyone who identifies himself as Jewish but cannot recites all the many many *many* laws of Judaism is only paying lip service to someone?

Comment: There are 10 commandments in the bible. There are 10 axioms of set theory. The many many many laws of Judaism you're referring to are more like the equivalents of the axiom of choice.

Comment: The term "lip service" carries with it a particular negative connotation, which is what I'm complaining about. I am well-aware that the working mathematician does not care one bit what is the formalization to which his mathematics can be reduced. As long as they can continue working, it's fine.

Comment: Yes, I want there to be a negative connotation because it is simply false that the set-theoretic foundation is a necessity for the working mathematician. It is a (tremendous) convenience, but so would be a different foundation, as long as it were universally accepted. It is the uniformity of the language and setup of mathematics that really helps, not the fact that there is a foundation in the philosophical sense of the word.

Comment: But the people you offend, or seem to show contempt to by using this negative language are set theorists who never claim that set theory is *necessary* in any way. The working mathematician who never cared to begin with still doesn't care. So pretty please with sugar on top, avoid being offensive.

Comment: Is this better now?

Comment: Much better. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thank you very much for this complete answer. Therefore, you mean all of them are equal and this equality can be proved by showing that all alphabets of each language can be translated into others'. Additionally, the simplicity preference decides which one should be used. Am I right?

Comment: I have attempted to formalize the set theory and rules of logic that it seems the average mathematician actually uses. They are the basis for software I have developed to teach undergrads the basic methods of proof (visit my website at http://www.dcproof.com ). There is only a passing resemblance to ZFC and "standard" FOL, but I think my system is much more intuitive and user-friendly. Anything you can prove using my system should be provable in ZFC and FOL, however.

Comment: @Fatimah: the connections go deeper than just "translating the alphabet" at the level of symbolic notation. The connections are of a mathematical nature, i.e., the structures involved are related to each other in interesting ways. I added a link to Steve Awodey's paper [From Sets to Types to Categories to Sets](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/preprints/stcsFinal.pdf) which explains this very well.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I will go through this article to find out more.